# Ordernar string que contém letras e números

Tags: java, string, comparação

Tenho uma uma lista de objetos que possui um inteiro e uma `String` (composta por letras e números). Gostaria de ordenar por esse inteiro e como segunda cláusula a ordem alfabética/numérica da string, então tentei usar o método `sort` da classe `Collections`.

Classe Mapa:

```
public class Mapa {
    private Integer sequencia;
    private String lote;

    //get e set
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mapa [sequencia=" + sequencia + ", lote=" + lote + "]";
    }
}
```

Classe de teste:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Mapa> mapas = new ArrayList<Mapa>();

        for (int i = 50; i > 0; i--) {
            Mapa mapa = new Mapa();
            mapa.setSequencia(1);
            mapa.setLote("Lote 00"+i);
            mapas.add(mapa);
        }

        Collections.sort(mapas, new Comparator<Mapa>() {

            public int compare(Mapa arg0, Mapa arg1) {
                Integer numSeqArg0 = arg0.getSequencia();
                String loteArg0 = arg0.getLote();

                Integer numSeqArg1 = arg1.getSequencia();
                String loteArg1 = arg1.getLote();

                Integer compareNumSequencia = numSeqArg0.compareTo(numSeqArg1);
                Integer compareLote = loteArg0.compareTo(loteArg1);

                return compareNumSequencia == 0 ? compareLote : compareNumSequencia;
            }
        });

        for (Mapa mapa : mapas) {
            System.out.println(mapa);
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 1]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 10]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 11]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 12]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 13]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 14]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 15]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 16]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 17]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 18]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 19]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 2]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 20]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 21]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 22]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 23]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 24]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 25]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 26]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 27]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 28]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 29]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 3]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 30]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 31]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 32]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 33]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 34]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 35]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 36]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 37]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 38]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 39]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 4]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 40]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 41]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 42]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 43]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 44]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 45]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 46]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 47]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 48]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 49]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 5]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 50]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 6]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 7]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 8]
Mapa [sequencia=1, lote=Lote 9]
```

Como podemos ver, a string está ficando ordenada de forma incorreta. Como posso fazer a ordenação de uma string por ordem alfabética, que também obedeça aos números que a compõe?

Comment: O titulo da pergunta não reflete a dúvida em si. Sugiro reescrever para algo mais claro como "ordenar `ArrayList` de objeto por `int` e `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você compara strings, até mesmo os dígitos são comparados levando-se em conta a [ordem lexicográfica](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) dos caracteres (ou seja, não é levado em conta seu valor numérico em si, em vez disso é feita uma comparação entre o valor dos [code points Unicode](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) dos caracteres).

Da mesma forma que `"abacate"` vem antes de `"abelha"` (pois a primeira e segunda letras são iguais, mas a terceira faz o "desempate"), `"Lote 40"` vem antes de `"Lote 5"`, pois os primeiros 5 caracteres são iguais ("Lote" e o espaço), e o caractere `4` faz o desempate (pois lexicograficamente ele vem antes do 5).

Se quer comparar a string e o respectivo valor numérico, isso deve ser feito separadamente. Você pode usar [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) para quebrar a string em duas partes, comparar a primeira ("Lote ") como string e a segunda como número:

```
Collections.sort(mapas, new Comparator<Mapa>() {
    public int compare(Mapa arg0, Mapa arg1) {
        Integer numSeqArg0 = arg0.getSequencia();
        Integer numSeqArg1 = arg1.getSequencia();
        int compareNumSequencia = numSeqArg0.compareTo(numSeqArg1);
        if (compareNumSequencia != 0) {
            // se número é diferente, não precisa comparar os lotes
            return compareNumSequencia;
        }
        String[] lote0Partes = arg0.getLote().split(" ");
        String[] lote1Partes = arg1.getLote().split(" ");

        int compareLote = lote0Partes[0].compareTo(lote1Partes[0]);
        int compareLoteNum = Integer.parseInt(lote0Partes[1]) - Integer.parseInt(lote1Partes[1]);

        return compareLote == 0 ? compareLoteNum : compareLote;
    }
});
```

O `split` separa a string por espaços, então o retorno é um array contendo duas strings: `Lote` e o respectivo número. Em seguida eu comparo a primeira parte, e se forem iguais eu uso [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) para transformar a segunda parte em número e faço a comparação de acordo com os valores numéricos.

Repare também que os métodos `compareTo` retornam um `int`, então não precisa atribuir o retorno a um `Integer` (o Java faz o *auto-boxing* automaticamente, mas neste caso só vamos comparar os valores numéricos depois, então pode usar `int` diretamente).